# Regular expression for decimal value upto some position

Tags: regex

In Input text box if somebody enter any value it should check the regular expression

maybe the value will be decimal or non decimal

before decimal it should have four digit

after decimal it should have only these three value (.25 , .75 , .5)

like:-

1.5

12.25

123.75

1234.75

1234

123

12

1

Please help me out

Comment: What about `.5` (without an integer part)? What about `1.50`? What about `2.0` or `2.00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^\d{1,4}(?:\.[27]?5)?$
```

Or, if you don't want to allow multiple zeros, as in `0000`, use this:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])(?:\.[27]?5)?$
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/21), see what matches and doesn't match.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\d{1,4}` matches one to four digits
- `(?:\.[27]?5)?` optionally matches a period, then an optional 2 or 7, then a 5
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: please tell me how to use in onkeyup function